# Polynomial Congurence Fields, I need help with this Theorem

Tags: polynomials, field-theory, congruences

I need help with proving this Theorem:

Let $F$ be a field. let $a(x), m(x)$ be polynomials in $F[x]$ with $m(x)$ of positive degree. The congruence class $[a(x)]_{m(x)}$ is a unit in $F[x]_{m(x)}$ if and only if $gcd(a(x),m(x)) = 1$

I think that if $gcd(a(x),m(x)) = 1$ then m(x) is a irreducible, and thus $a(x)$ is a unit in $F[x]_{m(x)}$? is that true?? any help would be greatful.

thanks.

Comment: Write $1$ as a linear combination of $a$ and $m$.

Comment: okay, because of bezout's identity we can write $1= a(x)U + m(x)V$? and what do I do next?

Comment: Reduce it mod $m$. What do you notice?

Comment: $a(x) \equiv 1 mod(m(x))$?? so $[a(x)]_{m(x)} = [1]_{m(x)}$ :D ?

Comment: Why did you lose the $U$?

Comment: sry $[a(x)U]_{m(x)} = [1]_{m(x)}$, I see it now thanks :)